# Steward badge not received on 1,000 reviews after 30 minutes

Tags: support, review-queues, badges

I've exactly 1,000 reviews on the suggested edits queue but I don't get the Steward badge after 30 minutes. However it stand checked on the review stats.

[image]

See here my recent achievements (the badge from the reviews isn't listed.

[image]

Comment: The badge was awarded 12 minutes after you posted this.

Comment: Why this question is -15 downvoted?

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia probably because the OP was impatient ... the comment from Martijn didn't help in that respect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry, just be patient:

> Most badges (with the exception of the [Informed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164073)) are awarded by a scheduled job which runs once every hour and are [non-deterministic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125108/295232), i.e. there is no *guarantee* that your badge will be awarded within an hour.

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232))

Congratulations in advance with your gold badge and [Foot of the Rainbow](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/foot-of-the-rainbow) hat!